# Where did the 'App Step' gone in my sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, app-permissions

So i'm creating a workflow with elevated permissions. I did all the steps to allow that following msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx And i don't have the option "App Step". I have Impersonation Step and this if i publish it will use my credentials to elevate permissions.

So is this different from App Step? I guess the difference would be that the workflow will just run in Full Control mode but not using my credentials with App Step. But i don't have that option. Do i have to go somewhere and add "App Step" to my ribbon? I tried customizing the SharePoint Designer ribbon but i don't see that option.

I create my workflow using SharePoint 2010 plateform because i want to copy an entire item to another list.

I use Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Comment: Are you have configured App Management application Service ?!

Comment: @M.Qassas You have to allow something in central administration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `app step` is not supported with `SharePoint 2010 platform` . it's ONLY supported with `SharePoint 2013 PLATFORM`

[image]

Comment: So basicly I can't copy an entire item in sharepoint 2013 workflow platform but i can use app step. OR i can copy an entire item in sharepoint 2010 workflow platform but have to use impersonation step. Huh why they make everything complicated :(

Comment: Simply, it's SharePoint :) ,